# Remove the same values when comparing multiple lists

Tags: c#, list, dropdown

I have 3 people living in 3 houses.

- Person A (Joe) lives in house 1.
- Person B (Jane) lives in house 2.
- Person C (Max) lives in house 3.

I have a button with which I make an assignment for certain persons. It becomes a kind of user administration. *E.g. person A has the permission to enter house C.*

I would like to be able to display only the houses that have **not been assigned yet**.

Illustrated as follows:

- Joe is the owner of house A and caretaker of house B.

If I want to assign him a new role now (caretaker of house C), I want only house C (the only unassigned house) to be displayed in the dropdown list.

[image]

Problem: Currently all houses are displayed.

**Code structure:**

I can create a new person or edit an existing person. I have an enum class for role assignment:

```
public enum RoleType
{
    [Display(Name = "Owner")]
    Owner = 0,

    [Display(Name = "Janitor")]
    Janitor = 1
}
```

I also have a model for role definition:

```
public class RoleDefinitionModel
{
    private RoleType? _role;
    private House _selectedHouse;
    
    public RoleDefinitionModel(IList<House> availableHouse, RoleType? selectedRole, House selectedHouse)
    {
        AvailableHouses = availableHouse;
        _role = selectedRole;
        _selectedHouse = selectedHouse;
        StartChangeTracking();
    }
    
    public virtual RoleType? SelectedRole
    {
        get { return _role; }
        set
        {
            if (_role == value)
                return;
            _role = value;
            NotifyChanges();
        }
    }
    
    public virtual House SelectedHouse
    {
        get { return _selectedHouse; }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedHouse == value)
                return;
            _selectedHouse = value;
            NotifyChanges();
        }
    }
    
    public virtual IList<House> AvailableHouses { get; }

    public virtual IList<RoleType> AvailableRoles { get; } = Enum<RoleType>.GetValues().ToList();
}
```

I already have an add and remove method, which also work. There is only one problem: When I click on the button I get my desired dropdown. But I can select all houses. And I only want to see the houses to which I have **not** been assigned a role yet.

```
public virtual void AddRoleDefinition()
{
    var roleDefinition = new RoleDefinitionModel(House, null, null);
    _roleDefinitions.Add(roleDefinition);
    this.SubscribeChanged(roleDefinition);
}
```

Which is the most effective way to check it:

- `Where()` and `Any()` from System.Linq:

`_roleDefinitions.Where(....Any());`

- `Contains()`
- or `Remove()` in a foreach-loop?

```
for (var i = selectedHouse.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (availableHouses.Contains(selectedHouse[i].Uid))
    {
        availableHouses.Remove(selectedHouse[i]);
    }
}

foreach (var selectedhouse in availableHouses)
{
    ...
}
```

However, I think this approach is wrong and my queries are wrong here. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not add a property to your House object such as :

```
public House()
{
   ...
   public bool HasBeenAssigned
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
}
```

Then use LINQ in order to select only those House objects that have not been assigned yet

```
public List<House> AvailableHouses 
{ 
  return ListOFHouses.Where(house => !house.HasBeenAssigned).Select(item => item).toList();
}
```

In regards to which method to adopt I would suggest - as per its use in my answer LINQ.

There is nothing wrong with the foreach loop - however as you can see the LINQ statement is more readable, maintainable, elegant and its shows intend.

The use of Where clause would be more appropriate in this case - we are looking in the list of house `where` the value of HasBeenAssigned is false. This will return a list on enumerable which we select and we cast as a list.

We are not interested if there are `any` which implies a boolean result. In fact the Any clause will return a boolean list.

Comment: Hi @AlexLeo, from your description and explanation of the facts this seems to be the best solution and especially as an easy implementation. I have incorporated the changes into my code and it seems to work well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @41 72 6c , I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two lists of houses.
The first one, a list of all houses in your system: `List<House> allHouses`.
The second one, a list of houses already assigned to a person: `List<House> assignedHouses`.
Then, the houses available for the assignment:

```
var allHouses = new[]
{
    new House { Uid = 1, Name = "House 1" },
    new House { Uid = 2, Name = "House 2" },
    new House { Uid = 3, Name = "House 3" },
};
var assignedHouses = new[] { allHouses[0] };

var availableHouses = allHouses.Where(house => assignedHouses.All(assigned => 
    assigned.Uid != house.Uid)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine($"Available houses: {string.Join(",", availableHouses.Select(i => i.Name))}");
Console.Read();
```

So, answering your question, the `Where(...All), seems the clearest way to get the houses which not assigned yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try a Except query:

`var availableHouses = allHouses.ToList().Except(assignedHouses).ToList();`

so you will get all available houses **except** assigned ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would say using LINQ with the current models/variables is the wrong tool for the job in this situation. Don't forget that even if you saved the results of a non-assigned house query with a `.ToList()`, the next time someone adds or removes a person to/from a house, you would need to execute the *entire* query again. That would mean going through two potentially long lists at the same time, and checking if elements of one are present in the other. That's pretty inefficient, especially if the lists are not sorted.

IMO a good solution might be to maintain 3 lists: `allHouses`, `assignedHouses` and `freeHouses`. Whenever you assign a house, you remove the reference to it from `freeHouses` and add it to `assignedHouses`. That way you always have access to the desired type of houses by simply iterating a single list.

Another possibility could be to modify the model for `House`, by adding references to the people who own that house. Then you might only use the list of `allHouses`, but you would get all free houses with the following query: `allHouses.Where(house => house.Owner == null)`. Or instead of a single `Owner` it could be a collection of all the people who have some relation to this `House`, but you get the point.

Comment: Hi @DanielCrha, Thank you very much for the effort and your answer, which has also helped me further.